# How can you access page properties (YAML front matter) within a converter plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm writing a converter plugin for Jekyll and need access to some of the page header (YAML front matter) properties.  Only the content is passed to the main converter method and does not seem possible to access the context.

Example:

```
module Jekyll
  class UpcaseConverter < Converter
    safe true
    priority :low

    def matches(ext)
      ext =~ /^\.upcase$/i
    end

    def output_ext(ext)
      ".html"
    end

    def convert(content)

      ###########
      #
      # Its here that I need access to the content page header data 
      #
      # 
      ###########

      content.upcase
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas how I can access the page header data within a converter plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Jekyll source code, it is not possible to retrieve the YAML front matter in a converter.

I see two solutions that could work depending on your situation.

1. Your file extension could be descriptive enough to provide the information you would have included in the front matter.  It looks like the Converter plugin was designed to be this basic.
2. If modifying Jekyll is an option, you could change the Convertible.transform method to send the front matter to Converter.convert.  The Converters that come with Jekyll would have to be modified as well.  Fork it on GitHub and see if others like the idea.  Here's where to start: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/blob/cb1a2d1818770ca5088818a73860198b8ccca27a/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb#L49

Good luck.

Comment: After going down a similar route I found the same - its not possible.  I also came to the conclusion that it **shoudn't** be possible as what I was trying to do was not suitable for a converter plugin, after a rethink I created tag plugins instead.  Converter plugins should only deal with converting text from one format to another and not be context sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

devnull, I ran into a similar situation and I figured a way of doing it.

In the converter, I registered a `pre-render` hook to pull YAML into a variable, so that in the actual `convert` method, I have access to the info I just pulled. Also, another `post_render` hook is needed to remove that piece of info since this should be a per-post data.

A side note. I found that the `convert` will be called twice, once for use in the html `<meta>` tag, once for the actual content. The hook will be only invoked for the second case, not the first. You may need to guard you `convert` function.

Another side note. I think having YAML in the converter is not unreasonable. Just like in `pandoc` where you can specify bibliography file in the YAML section and do other fine tuning, people should be given freedom to customize a single post using YAML, too.

```
  def initialize(config)
    super(config)

    Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :pre_render do |post|
      if matches(post.data["ext"])
        # extract per post metadata, including those in YAML
        @myconfig["meta"] = post.data

        # you may need the path to the post: post.path
      end
    end 

    Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :post_render do |post|
      if matches(post.data["ext"])
        # remove per post metadata
        @myconfig.delete("meta")
      end
    end
  end 

  def convert(content) 
    return content unless @myconfig["meta"]

    # actual conversion goes here
  end
```